# unable to find the core data sqlite table location

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Am unable to find the location of sqlite file

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C06C578B-C1A5-4D82-A5A1-E5D091C9E18A/Documents/XYZTR.sqlite

Comment: Are you using the device for testing?

Comment: Please see my answer, It will help in device and simulator both.

Comment: yes am getting this path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C06C578B-C1A5-4D82-A‌​5A1-E5D091C9E18A/Doc‌​uments/XYZTR.sqlite but in my mac the location is not getting is any way to give the location manually.

Comment: @ManjuSSP For device location you have to download iFunBox to getting path to your databse. iFunBox access all the file of single application through icon to database file and also plist file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this environmental variable in your projecct

Xcode > your project > Product menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run

Set this

**-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1** 
  in Arguments passed on Launch.

Everytime your projects runs It will print your path to SQLite database.

Hope this thing help you.

Comment: yes am getting this path
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C06C578B-C1A5-4D82-A5A1-E5D091C9E18A/Documents/XYZTR.sqlite
but in my mac the location is not getting is any way to give the location manually.

Comment: you can find path through finder in your mac

Comment: @ManjuSSP This is simple way to print your sqlite databse path in device or even in simulator. Copy and paste that path into finder, it will redirect to your database to the place

Comment: If it helps, Can you accept my answer or upvote the same ?

Comment: No its not getting the location i tried with that already.showing like there is no search path

Comment: @ManjuSSP Did you check it after iFunBox download ?

Comment: yes i installed but how to use that.and how i can see the database on there

Comment: Just connect your device and go to application

Comment: in iFunBox i choose my application showing error 
App Sandbox access is restricted by Apple to access with.........jailbreak is required to open the sandbox of this App

Comment: Sorry, but mine application are opening. So ,I can't do anything.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the support :). My device is jailed one that y.....want to find another solution. is any way to see the table lively. means running time want to see the table structure now am downloading the 
Window > Devices > YourDeviceName > YourAppName > Cog under 'Installed Apps' list >(Pop-Up - select) Download Container
Save to location > Right click on 'YourAppName.xcappdata' > Select 'Show Package Contents'> AppData > Documents > YourDatabase.sqlite

and viewing  structure its very deficult to check all the time is you know anything.

Comment: No, I just tell you everything I know. It's my priviledge to help you. Welcome

Comment: @ManjuSSP will you upvote the same for this understanding to you/

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy database from Device and then open this database in your tool .

> In Xcode select window->organizer and expand the node next to your
>   application in the applications section on your phone. Select the
>   black downward pointing arrow next to application data and save the
>   file anywhere on your desktop. Your sqlite database should be in there
>   somewhere.

**Steps**

1. First you need to run project

   1. **Xcode > Open > YourProject > Product > Run**
   2. **Window > Devices > YourDeviceName > YourAppName > Cog under 'Installed Apps' list >(Pop-Up - select) Download Container**
   3. **Save to location > Right click on 'YourAppName.xcappdata' > Select 'Show Package Contents'> AppData > Documents > YourDatabase.sqlite**